# Redis: INFO doesn't report network/bandwidth metrics?

Tags: iptables, traffic, redis, metrics

Is there a way to get network/bandwidth metrics from a given Redis process?  Something I missed in the output of the INFO command?  Some patch or compile time configuration option?

Or would I need to add some `iptables` packet counting commands and write something to poll those instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed INFO commands does not return informations about network/bandwidth out-of-the-box so you have to either fork redis or use iptables.

**[Update]** I checked and I can confirm that even `client list` does not display network/bandwidth metric. Maybe you should submit a feature request if you think other users have the same issue.